# IE 11 bug: nested nav won't display in block format

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, nav

I have a nested nav which is working fine in every other browser but IE 11 of course. 
The HTML is below:

```
<nav id="nav">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="holder">
                <ul class="leftside-menu">
                    <li class="show-menu"><a href="">Benefits</a>
                        <ul class="leftside-nested-menu">
                            <li><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Performance.aspx">Performance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Installation.aspx">Installation</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hideIt"><a href="Design.aspx">Design</a></li>
                    <li class="hideIt"><a href="Performance.aspx">Performance</a></li>
                    <li class="hideIt"><a href="Installation.aspx">Installation</a></li>
                    <li><a style="z-index: 10;" href="Testing.aspx">Testing</a></li>
                    <li><a class="getWidth" href="Resources.aspx">Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="map">Map</a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</nav>
```

And here is the CSS for the display:

```
            .leftside-menu {
                display: inline;
                padding: 0;
            }

                .leftside-menu li {
                    display: inline;
                    list-style-type: none;
                    position: relative;
                }

            .leftside-nested-menu {
                position: absolute;
                display: none;
                z-index: -1;
            }

                .leftside-nested-menu li:nth-child(n+2) a {
                    margin: 0;
                }

            .show-menu:hover > a {
                color: #b99a3a;
            }

            .show-menu:hover .leftside-nested-menu {
                display: inline-block;
                top: 40px;
            }

            nav.sticky .leftside-nested-menu {
                background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
                padding: 0 25px 15px;
            }

            .leftside-menu li.hideIt {
                display: none;
            }

            @media only screen and (max-width: 1028px) {
                .leftside-menu li.hideIt {
                    display: block;
                }

                .leftside-menu li.show-menu, .leftside-menu li.show-menu a {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
```

I am not sure what other options there are. I have tried display: inline in IE developer tools and it worked for the vertical display but it pushed it way off to the side. It is not respecting absolute positioning within the relative parent. 
Any other ideas to make this work? 
Thanks in advance. 
CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/sazad/pen/YOeQPp

This is what is showing in my IE 11 if I change it to .show-menu:hover .leftside-nested-menu display to inline-block:

[image]

Comment: https://codepen.io/sazad/full/YOeQPp/ works the same in IE11 and latest FF . I would use inline-block  for .leftside-menu and .show-menu

Comment: @G-Cyr Please look at the image I attached.Why is it moving so far left? It should be under benefits.

Comment: there must some other css rule implied or a typo in the html structure. your codepen does'nt show that funny behavior.